# Is there a software engineering concept/pattern for "service injection"?

Tags: http, design-patterns, microservices, software-design

I'm implementing a service that needs to call another service that calculates a result in a way I cannot know.

Let's say I have the following scenario:
I have some place in my code, calling a HTTP request to a defined endpoint another service returning a defined result. Now, **I mustn't dictate how the result will be calculated**, however I can define the result output data type I'm expecting. I want to put emphasis on this, since otherwise I would just implement the calculation logic in my service.

I would then describe it to the user:

> You need to provide an HTTP service, with this exact endpoint, receiving these exact parameters, delivering this exact result type, but how you calculate the result is your job. I just need the URL of your service.

Afterwards the user of my service would configure the URL to their HTTP service into my service, so that I can make a HTTP request to `{url}/defined-endpoint`.

I couldn't think of another name but "service-injection" to describe this concept, since it has a resemblance to dependency injection, just that in code you don't provide an object instance, but a service that is called via http.

**My question is**: Is there a pattern for this concept or an alternative that more elegantly solves the general problem of outsourcing a calculation to another service?

Comment: You mean ["interface-based programming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface-based_programming)? You may call this an "architectural pattern", if you like.

Comment: I do not mean interface-based-programming in the way it is described in your link, since it refers to packages that have to be installed and then are available at compile time. I meant a call to a service, within my service that expects a result from a specific endpoint. In fact, it would be interface-based-programming, however not with classes or packages, but with running services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining a contract of how the interface between your service and the other service. This means that as long as the contract is respected by both parties the integration and communication will succeed. Not sure if "service-injection" is a good terminology for this. You are not injecting something in your own service, you are simply delegating the calculation to another one, but you don't inject the logic of the service into your own. And that is good because then you have a good separation of concerns and loose coupling. As long as the contract is respected, both services can be changed in whatever way it is needed and the integration would still hold.

> Is there a pattern for this concept or an alternative that more elegantly solves the general problem of outsourcing a calculation to another service?

This is just how things work in a micro-services ecosystem. You have multiple services exposing APIs that communicate with each other to provide as a whole a higher-order functionality.

Comment: Is this a general known or agreed-upon concept, that microservices always provide these sorts of contracts? Or to be only operational if another microservice is provided? If so, is there a name for this concept that I can further research?

Comment: Well, usually yes. Micro-services are usually only a cog in a larger machine which means that so that they are useful they will need to expose some useful API in order for other services to consume it as needed. This is one of the basic concepts of micro-services on which multiple separated services rely on each other based on these contracts (REST APIs usually) to achieve some functionality. You can find some detailed information about this at https://dzone.com/articles/integration-patterns-in-microservices-world. I would define your case as following an "API Integration Pattern".